# Mininet Real World Network Topologies

Tags: networking, simulation, mininet, topology

I was wondering how I can simulate real-world network topologies in Mininet. For example, how can I simulate a campus network? Or even harder, how can I simulate an ISP network topology? Any guidance and ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe this question needs to be asked in [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simulate a campus or ISP network you will need a network topology first. A good place to look is [Boston Network Topology Generator](http://www.cs.bu.edu/brite/).